# Order of elements in an external direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone explain why the largest order of an element in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 $ is 12?

Also, why does $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ have no elements of order 12?

How do you find the possible orders of elements in these external direct products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is that an element $(a,b)\in G\times H$ has order $\rm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$.

It's straight forward to see why this is based on the way the group operation is defined (component wise) on the product.

The two results you mentioned follow.

Comment: I'm not sure how the first result follows. I see that $3\times 4 = 12$, but what about the 3 2's? Also should the $G \times H$ be $G \oplus H$?

Comment: $\rm{lcm}(2,2,2,3,4)=12$.  In the case of a direct product of a finite number of groups the two coincide.

Comment: Okay thanks.....